# Flutter image_picker problem on iOS device Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm running into a very odd error on M1 Macbook when developing for iOS devices. This is a simple picture picking functionality within the Flutter template (full code [here](https://github.com/lucaphen/camera_test)). This works perfectly fine on Android, but not Apple iPhone simulator (running iOS 14 on simulator), where it gives an error that returns null.

```
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          await _getImageFromGallery();
          //print('Image selected');
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
```

Below is the image picking function for **image_picker: ^0.8.3+1**. I tried a few different versions with minimal success.

```
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  File? imagePath;

  Future _getImageFromGallery() async {
    try {
      var pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      print('pickedFile: ${pickedFile!.path}');
      setState(() {
        imagePath = File(pickedFile.path);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      print('error: $error');
    }
  }
```

If anyone could help that would be much appreciated!

Comment: image_picker is not working perfectly on ios simulators. Try your code on real device.

Comment: Thanks. I tested it on a real device and its working now.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a permission problem, you can check out the [permission_handler package](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) and see if that fixes your issue.

Answer (score -1):

Add This Permission in Your Android mainfest File

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

For IOS Add This Line to /ios/Runner/Info.plist:

```
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>Microphone Access Required</string>
<key>NSMotionUsageDescription</key>
<string>Motion Usage Required</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>Please allow access to photo library so you can easily upload your photos.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Please allow access to photo library so you can easily upload your photos.</string>
```

**Add this line in pubspec**

> image_picker : ^0.8.4

This is code i am currently using for my app.

```
onTap: () async{
    String path = await getImagePath();

    print(path);
    if(path != "Exceed Limit" && path!="noselect")
    {
      File imagefile = File(path);
    }
}

Future<String> getImagePath() async{
     final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
    // Pick an image
    final XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (image?.path != null) {
        print(image!.path);
        int size = await image.length();
        double sizevalueinmb = size / (1024 * 1024);
        if (sizevalueinmb < 5) {
            String path = image.path;
            return path;
        } 
        else {
            print("Your Image File Exceeded Size Limit of 5mb !");
            return "Exceed Limit";
        }
    } 
    else {
    print("User Not Selected Any Image");
    return "noselect";
    }
}
```

Comment: It's an issue related to iOS permissions but your answer includes solutions for Android. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I don't think it's permission problem because image picker has inbuild property to ask permission and I am also using it without permission handler package. If your problem still occurs than you need to store your image in localtempdirectory and retrieve it from there for that you can use path provider package. Because sometimes in ios the mainactivity end before the image picker finish the image picking.